# Problemas ao configurar rotas em servidor apache2 com laravel 5.1

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

Estava fazendo um projeto local e sempre o rodava com `php artisan serve` e tudo ia perfeitamente agora que estou subindo o projeto para uma maquina da digitalocean estou tendo problemas com as rotas está acontecendo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

me parece que a view não está sendo encontrada, estou utilizando um servidor apache2 com virtualhost apontando para a pasta public do projeto e até ai tudo bem por que cai na welcome.blade.php tranquilamente mas as outras view que estão em outros diretórios não estão sendo encontradas.

Seria algum problema de direcionamento de diretórios? ou alguma configuração do laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve prestar atenção (principalmente se você é usuário do Windows) que servidores Linux (que no caso é a maioria, principalmente os compartilhados) fazem diferença entre maiúscula e minúsculas, diferentemente do Windows.

Você deve verificar se você definiu as pastas das `views` com todos os caracteres em minúsculo (pois esse é o padrão do Laravel).

Se você fizer isso no `Windows` vai funcionar, mas não no `Linux`, por conta da diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas:

```
 app/
    views/
        minhaViewLegal.blade.php


view('minhaviewlegal', [])
```

Comment: sim mas não uso linux eu uso mac mas porem sei que os dois são baseados em unix, mas no caso sua resposta está parcialmente certa, porem a questão é que o servidor embutido do laravel reconhece isso mas o apache não reconhece.